# Formatting form fields

Tags: html, css

I have a Django form with some Charfields, however when a user enters a value which exceeds the width of the box, they have to scroll to see what they have wrote. Is there a way to make it so that the boxes get bigger if a longer value is entered?

Comment: This cant be done by Django, I guess. it's a front end issue.

Comment: @InesTlili how would I go about doing this then

Comment: Edit your post and post your template so I can help you

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).